# How can I run all the methods in one go for parameterized tests in Junit

Tags: junit

```
   While using parameterized tests in Junit, if there are three test methods(method 1, method 2 and method 3) and 2 input parameters("hello","world").

    Method 1 first runs for hello than World 
    Method 2 runs for hello than world and so on.

    Example: 
    method 1 --> hello
    method 1 --> world
    method 2 --> hello
    method 2 --> world
    method 3 --> hello
    method 3 --> world
```

Is there a way that first all the methods run for the first parameter , than for the 2nd one.
        example:

```
    method 1 --> hello
    method 2 --> hello
    method 3 --> hello
    method 1 --> world
    method 2 --> world
    method 3 --> world
```

Comment: simply write a separated `@Parameterized` test to fullfill your needs. consider extract a super class if there are some same logic between the 2 tests.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to achieve what you want without writing an own `@Parameterized` runner.